# C# code works but errors occur while packaging my UWP application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, packaging

I have created a UWP application in Visual Studio.  I plan on using it only for side loading(it is a LOB app).  It doesn't have any errors.  But when I try to package it, I get the following errors.

[Errors in Packaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBDSP.jpg)

> 0X8007000b an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Also, here is my output console.

[image: Output]

How do I fix this?

Comment: How about the result if you are creating a blank UWP app and try to create a package?

Comment: Please try to create the package only target x86, don't target x64, and try again.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT The blank UWP app package without any problems.  I get the same error messages when I only target x86 or when I only target x64.

Comment: I have fixed the warning CS0108 but the other errors persist.

Comment: Try Clear Solution and Rebuild Solution

Comment: @VijayNirmal I cleaned and rebuilt the solution without any errors but  the problem once again arose when I tried packaging the solution.

Comment: You want to repeat the same process (Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution) for all configuration (Release-x86,Release-x64,Release-ARM)

Comment: @VijayNirmal After doing that I got identical results as originally.

Comment: So your project is successful building in debug configuration but not in release configuration. Am I right?

Comment: @VijayNirmal It is successfully building in both debug and release mode for all configurations.  The errors occur when I try to package it.

Comment: Please update your thread to upload the current exceptions after you fixed CS0108 error.

Comment: @CadeEngen seems to be an issue with "scale-50". Do you have any resource like app logo which is defined for scale-50 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From the solution explorer, double click and open `Package.appxmanifest`
  Click on `Visual Assets` tab on top. It is second from left, after `Application` tab.
- Select a source image (this is the image you want to use for logos, badges, splash screen, etc.)
- Under assets combo box, select all `All Visual Assets`
- Hit Generate
- Say ok that it will overwrite your existing files

Now, if you want to use a different image for any of the specific areas, for example, App Icon, scroll down, and provide a different source for it.

Now, build and make sure your app builds. Then attempt to create the app package again.